# Why do the withdraw and deiconify commands not work within functions? (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I have my main code using the withdraw and deiconify commands which work. When i apply them to different functions (which dont affect the main code), they dont seem to work.

I get the following error:

> homeButton = Button(content, width=50, height=50, command=lambda:[homePage.deiconify(), resourcePage.destroy()])
> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'deiconify'

Ive taken a small piece of relevant code from my code so you can test it if you would like

Just click submit button on the first page, click the resources button on the next page, and the home button in the top left of the page will be the one that is not working how it should be

```
from tkinter import *

def resourcePage():
    global homeIcon
    global file

    resource = Toplevel()
    resource.title("Resource Page")
    resource.resizable(0, 0)

    header = LabelFrame(resource, bg="white")
    content = LabelFrame(resource, bg="white")

    header.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)  # Forces column to expand to fill all available space
    homeButton = Button(content, width=50, height=50, command=lambda:[homePage.deiconify(), resourcePage.destroy()])   
     #HERE IS THE ERROR ^^
    try:
        homeIcon = PhotoImage(file="yes.png")
        homeButton.config(image=homeIcon)
        homeButton.image = homeIcon
    except TclError:
        print("Home")
    homeButton.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w", padx=2, pady=2)

    # each section of code below is for their respective labels on the page
    papersLabel = Label(content, text="Exam Papers", bg="#12a8e3", fg="white", font=("Ariel", 26, "bold"),
                        activebackground="#12a8e3", anchor="w", padx=15)
    papersLabel.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=15, pady=(15, 5), ipadx=429, ipady=10)
    papersPhysics = Label(content, text="Physics:", bg="white", font=("Ariel", 22), anchor="w")
    papersPhysics.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="w", padx=20)
    papersHyperlinks = Label(content, text="• Hyperlinks here", bg="white", font=("Ariel", 18), anchor="w")
    papersHyperlinks.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky="w", padx=24)
    papersCS = Label(content, text="Computer Science:", bg="white", font=("Ariel", 22), anchor="w")
    papersCS.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky="w", padx=20)
    papersHyperlinks = Label(content, text="• Hyperlinks here", bg="white", font=("Ariel", 18), anchor="w")
    papersHyperlinks.grid(row=6, column=0, sticky="w", padx=24)

    questionsLabel = Label(content, text="Practice Exam Questions:", bg="#12a8e3", fg="white",
                           font=("Ariel", 26, "bold"), activebackground="#12a8e3", anchor="w", padx=15)
    questionsLabel.grid(row=7, column=0, padx=15, pady=(25, 5), ipadx=328, ipady=10)
    questionsPhysics = Label(content, text="Physics:", bg="white", font=("Ariel", 22), anchor="w")
    questionsPhysics.grid(row=8, column=0, sticky="w", padx=20)
    questionsHyperlinks = Label(content, text="• Hyperlinks here", bg="white", font=("Ariel", 18), anchor="w")
    questionsHyperlinks.grid(row=9, column=0, sticky="w", padx=24)
    questionsCS = Label(content, text="Computer Science:", bg="white", font=("Ariel", 22), anchor="w")
    questionsCS.grid(row=10, column=0, sticky="w", padx=20)
    questionsHyperlinks = Label(content, text="• Hyperlinks here", bg="white", font=("Ariel", 18), anchor="w")
    questionsHyperlinks.grid(row=11, column=0, sticky="w", padx=24)

    videosLabel = Label(content, text="Helpful Videos:", bg="#12a8e3", fg="white", font=("Ariel", 26, "bold"),
                        activebackground="#12a8e3", anchor="w", padx=15)
    videosLabel.grid(row=12, column=0, padx=15, pady=(25, 5), ipadx=415, ipady=10)
    videosPhysics = Label(content, text="Physics:", bg="white", font=("Ariel", 22), anchor="w")
    videosPhysics.grid(row=13, column=0, sticky="w", padx=20)
    videosHyperlinks = Label(content, text="• Hyperlinks here", bg="white", font=("Ariel", 18), anchor="w")
    videosHyperlinks.grid(row=14, column=0, sticky="w", padx=24)
    videosCS = Label(content, text="Computer Science:", bg="white", font=("Ariel", 22), anchor="w")
    videosCS.grid(row=15, column=0, sticky="w", padx=20)
    videosHyperlinks = Label(content, text="• Hyperlinks here", bg="white", font=("Ariel", 18), anchor="w")
    videosHyperlinks.grid(row=16, column=0, sticky="w", padx=24,
                          pady=(0, 25))  # y padding here to keep some space from the bottom of the page

    header.grid(row=0, sticky='NSEW')
    content.grid(row=1, sticky='NSEW')

def homePage():
    homePage = Toplevel()
    homePage.title("Home Page")
    homePage.resizable(0, 0)

    header = LabelFrame(homePage, bg="#12a8e3")
    content = LabelFrame(homePage, bg="white")

    header.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)  # Forces column to expand to fill all available space

    title = Label(header, text="School Subjects Quiz", bg="#12a8e3", fg="white", font=("Ariel", 35, "bold"), padx=10,
                  pady=10)
    title.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)

    # I will add thumbnails to the buttons in later development phases
    questionsButton = Button(content, text="Questions", padx=380, pady=100, bg="#12a8e3", fg="white",
                             font=("Ariel", 45, "bold"), activebackground="#12a8e3", command=lambda:[subjectSelection(), homePage.withdraw()])
    questionsButton.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=15, pady=40)

    accountButton = Button(content, text="Account", padx=100, pady=135, bg="#12a8e3", fg="white",
                           font=("Ariel", 45, "bold"), activebackground="#12a8e3", command=lambda:[accountPage(), homePage.withdraw()])
    accountButton.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=30, pady=35)

    resourceButton = Button(content, text="Revision" + "\n" + "Resources", padx=100, pady=100, bg="#12a8e3", fg="white",
                            font=("Ariel", 45, "bold"), activebackground="#12a8e3", command=lambda:[resourcePage(), homePage.withdraw()])
    resourceButton.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=30, pady=35)

    header.grid(row=0, sticky='NSEW')
    content.grid(row=1, sticky='NSEW')

#Creating the log in page
root = Tk()
root.title("Log-in page")
root.geometry('1000x850')   #creates dimensions of page
root.resizable(0,0)      #will disable max/min tab of window

#seperating the page into sections
header = LabelFrame(root, bg="#12a8e3")
content = LabelFrame(root, bg="white")

root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1) # 100%
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=2) # 2%
root.rowconfigure(1, weight=98) # 98%

#creating the title of the page to be displayed in the header
title = Label(header, text="School Subjects Quiz", bg="#12a8e3", fg="white", font=("Ariel",65, "bold"), padx=10, pady=10)
title.pack(expand=TRUE)

#username input box
usernameLabel = Label(content, width = 60, borderwidth=5, font=("Ariel", 22), text="Enter Username", bg="white", anchor="w", padx=100)
usernameLabel.pack(ipady = 8,  pady=(55,0))
usernameBox = Entry(content, width = 60, borderwidth=5, font=("HelvLight", 18))
usernameBox.pack(ipady = 10)

#password input box
passwordLabel = Label(content, width = 60, borderwidth=5, font=("Ariel", 22), text="Enter Password", bg="white", anchor="w", padx=100)
passwordLabel.pack(ipady = 8, pady=(55,0))
passwordLabel = Entry(content, width = 60, borderwidth=5, font=("HelvLight", 18))
passwordLabel.pack(ipady = 10)

#submit buttons for inputs
submitButton = Button(content, width = 20, borderwidth=5, font=("Ariel", 22), text="Submit", bg="#b5b5b5", fg="black", activebackground="#b5b5b5", command=lambda:[homePage(), root.withdraw()])
submitButton.pack(ipady = 5, pady=(15,0))

#button to click on to make an account
registerButton = Button(content, width = 40, borderwidth=5, font=("Ariel", 24), text="New? Click here to register", bg="#12a8e3", fg="white", activebackground="#12a8e3", command=lambda:[register(), root.withdraw()])
#withdraw hides the window and register calls upon the register function
registerButton.pack(ipady = 20, pady=(100,0))

header.grid(row=0, sticky='news')
content.grid(row=1, sticky='news')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You use `homePage` both for a function and a local variable.

Comment: You're trying to use the same name for your window objects, and the functions that create those windows.  Calling `.deiconify()` on a *function* is utterly meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments are right, you are mixing up function names and variable names. You can solve it as follows:

- Rename all `HomePage` variables to (for example) `HomePg`, except of course for the function name and the function call in `submitButton`.
- Now you run into a second problem: `HomePg` is a local function variable which is unknown to the `resourcePage()` function. A quick way to solve it is to make it global by adding `global homePg` immediately after `def homePage()`
- This solves the original error, but reveals another one: you are trying to destroy the function `resourcePage()` (same line as the original error). Change this to: `resource.destroy()`.

After this, your code should be running error-free.